# What and c++ exception

Tags: c++, exception

I tried to create my custom exception class for printing helpful message's sakes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

class invalid_input_exception : public std::exception
{
private:
    const char* input;
public:
    invalid_input_exception(const char *);
    const char* what() const noexcept;
};

invalid_input_exception::invalid_input_exception(const char * input) : input(input) { }

const char * invalid_input_exception::what() const noexcept
{
    std::string message;
    message.append("Occured on: ")
            .append(input);
    return message.c_str();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const char* str = "Aaaaa";
    throw invalid_input_exception(str);
}
```

But it doesn't excatly work because after throwing the instance of `invalid_input_exception` the `what()` message was actually empty.

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2617dd64fb8f1bf8)

What was wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
 return message.c_str();
```

`message` is local to the function, and you're returning a pointer to its internal buffer. Undefined behaviour ensues.

Answer (score 2):

`message` is a local variable, which has been destroyed when out of `invalid_input_exception::what()`, and the pointer returned by `string::c_str()` became invalid too.

You need to deep copy the content here, and might store it to the member variable `input`. And pay attention to the allocation and deallocation of it.

Comment: So, I should just make a copy of that pointer and return it instead, right?

Comment: @stella Yes, you can use `memcpy` etc. Pay attention to that the size is enough for it, maybe a memory allocation is reqiured.

Comment: If you're talking about the deep copy, the just coyping the pointer will not be enough... I'm confused...

Comment: @stella Just copying the pointer is not enough, because the memory it points to will be invalid when out of the function `what`.

Answer (score 1):

Two main problems here:

1. `message` is a local variable and will go out of scope at the end of `what` - thus the returned pointer is not pointing to valid string conent.
2. The exception class MUST make a copy of the passed message since you cannot expect the source of the message to be still valid at the point the exception will be catched.

You could go for

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>

class invalid_input_exception : public std::exception
{
private:
  std::string input;
public:
  invalid_input_exception(const char *in) : input(in) 
  {
    input = "Occured on: " + input;
  }
  const char* what() const noexcept
  {
    return input.c_str();
  }
};
```

or you use `runtime_error` as a base which has a message-copy-constructor and `what`:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

class invalid_input_exception : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
  invalid_input_exception(const char *in) : 
    runtime_error(("Occured on" + std::string(in)).c_str())
  { }
  const char* what() const noexcept
  {
    return runtime_error::what();
  }
};
```

Comment: My upv because it's the only answer (so far) to explictly point out input string may be gone and exceptions are bubbled by value

Answer (score 0):

Consider this implementation instead:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class invalid_input_exception : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    invalid_input_exception(const std::string& msg): std::runtime_error{ msg }{}
};
```

This is better for the following reasons:

- The `what()` member function is already implemented by `std::runtime_error`, to work with a `std::string`.
- Your exception class is a `std::runtime_error` (inheriting from std::exception dirrectly only makes sense when it is imposed by the module's design, or when you need an exception offering another data format (that is, different than a text message). Alternately, you could inherit from `std::logic_error`.
- The class manages it's resources correctly, through the use of `std::string`.